# Move Uploaded FIle error CakePHP 2.x

Tags: file, cakephp, upload, directory

I am trying to upload a file to the webroot/files directory.
I also include a record of the file in my database table.

The saving of the file to the database works, and I use the move_uploaded_file() method, but it does not work.  It doesn't return any errors, but the files doesn't show up in the files folder.  I checked permissions and they are all 755.
Here is the action in my controller:

```
if ($this->request->is('post'))
  {
      $uploadedFile = array();
      $filename = $this->request->data['Document']['MyFile']['name'];
      $fileData = fread(fopen($this->request->data['Document']['MyFile']['tmp_name'], "r"), $this->request->data['Document']['MyFile']['size']);

      $uploadedFile['MyFile']['name'] = $this->request->data['Document']['MyFile']['name'];
      $uploadedFile['MyFile']['type'] = $this->request->data['Document']['MyFile']['type'];
      $uploadedFile['MyFile']['size'] = $this->request->data['Document']['MyFile']['size'];
      $uploadedFile['MyFile']['data'] = $fileData;

  $filePath = WEBROOT_DIR . DS . 'files' . DS . $uploadedFile['MyFile']['name'];
 debug($filePath);
      if (move_uploaded_file($filename, $filePath))
      {
          echo "No Error";
          $this->Session->setFlash('Uploaded file has been moved SUCCESS.');
      }
      else
      {
          $this->Session->setFlash('Unable to Move file.');
      }
      if ($this->MyFile->save($uploadedFile))
      {
          $this->Session->setFlash('Uploaded file has been saved.');
      }
      else
      {
          $this->Session->setFlash('Unable to save file.');
      }
  }
```

This is the output from the `debug($filePath);`
'webroot/files/filename' -> where filename is the actual name of the file uploaded.

Any help would be great.
Thanks

Update------------------------------------------------
I debugged $this->request->data and this is the output when i upload a small file.

```
array(
    'Document' => array(
        'MyFile' => array(
            'name' => 'add.ctp',
            'type' => 'application/octet-stream',
            'tmp_name' => '/tmp/phpcxBA9B',
            'error' => (int) 0,
            'size' => (int) 3700
        )
    )
)
```

I also added an else statement below the `move_uploaded_file()` and it does set the flash to Unable to move file.

I'm still not sure why, can it be the `$filename` and `$filePath` variables?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move 'tmp_name', i.e.

```
$filename = $this->request->data['Document']['MyFile']['tmp_name'];
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the constant `WWW_ROOT` instead of `WEBROOT_DIR`? 
You need to provide the path to the file system.

Comment: Have you tried setting folder permissions to 777? PHP requires write permissions for 'others'

Comment: yes, the permissions are set to 777 for that folder. Do you want to see my view code as well? Would that help?

Comment: Did you use the CakePHP form helper to create the form, and did you add the 'type' => 'file' attribute to it, so that PHP can handle the upload? It adds the following attribute to the form tag: enctype="multipart/form-data"

Comment: yes, I did.  The code is able to enter all the info into the database, it just can't move the file, which is wierd.

Comment: Hey, I got it to work. my problem was the first parameter to the `move_uploaded_file()` function.  I needed to use the tmp_name of the file. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You May face problem with this:

```
$filePath = WEBROOT_DIR . DS . 'files' . DS . $uploadedFile['MyFile']['name'];
```

The Error message will be like:

```
move_uploaded_file(webroot\files\File_Name): failed to open stream: No such file or directory [APP\Controller\CustomerController.php cakephp
```

If so, Replace the above line with this:

```
$filePath = WWW_ROOT . DS . 'files' . DS . $uploadedFile['MyFile']['name'];
```

Means,

```
WEBROOT_DIR . DS .
```

with

```
WWW_ROOT .
```

and it will move the Uploaded file.